# Is Newton's third law independent of the frame being inertial or non-inertial?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

It is known that for Newton's second law to be valid it is fundamentally necessary that the system under study be an inertial reference, which automatically creates a direct dependence of the second law with Newton's first law. But does Newton's third law depend on the inertial frame or is it valid for any inertial or non-inertial system?

Comment: The third law is basically momentum conservation, so it won't hold in a non-inertial frame.

Comment: @J.G. what have you to say about Ranjeet Tate's answer here: https://www.quora.com/Is-Newtons-Third-Law-applicable-in-non-inertial-frames#:~:text=TL%3BDR%3A%20Yes.,applied%20on%20one%20of%20them.

Comment: @BobD The occasional typo aside, Tate's calculations rescue the third law by modifying the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Third law does not hold in non-inertial frame. Let there be non-inertial frame moving with constant acceleration $\mathbf a$ with respect to inertial frame.

In that non-inertial frame, every body will experience apparent force  $-m \mathbf a$ where $m$ is mass of the body. This apparent force has no counterpart.

Comment: What do you mean is that in a non-inertial frame where fictitious forces arise there will not be a reaction to these forces? Well, let's suppose two people on top of a car with acceleration **a**. If one person pushes the other, shouldn't there be an action and reaction between them even though they are on top of the accelerated car?

Comment: Yes, the action-reaction force pairs that are present in inertial frame will be present also in non-inertial frame and for these, the third law still holds. But in non-inertial frame there will also appear "inertial" forces $-m\mathbf a$ which are without action-reaction counterparts, so third law does not hold for those.